# How to write text, draw a line and then again write text in a pdf file using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Requirement: Attached the screen shot. I have to write 2 lines of text in the pdf and then draw a line and then again start writing some texts.

Accordingly, my algorithm goes by:

```
contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
contentStream.beginText();
```

Created a new PDPageContentStream and triggered the function beginText(). I am able to write the upper text portion as displayed in the image attached.

Given below is the following lines of code for the upper text and the lines:

```
        contentStream.showText("Entry Form – Header");
        yCordinate -= fontHeight;  //This line is to track the yCordinate
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
        yCordinate -= leading;
        contentStream.showText("Date Generated: " + dateFormat.format(date));
        yCordinate -= fontHeight;
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
        yCordinate -= leading;
        contentStream.endText(); // End of text mode
```

I had to end this text mode because the below 3 lines of code (which draws a line) won't execute in text mode:

```
            contentStream.moveTo(startX, yCordinate);
            contentStream.lineTo(endX, yCordinate);
            contentStream.stroke();
```

Now After this line of code, if I write :

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.showText("Name: XXXXX");
```

The Name is displayed at the below left cornor of the page. I want this line to be next after the line drawn as displayed in the below image.

Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: `beginText()` ... show first two text lines ... `endText()` ... stroke graphic line ... `beginText()` ... position text matrix for next text line ... show remaining text lines.

Comment: I am facing problem in placing the text matrix for next text line after the lines drawn. I tried `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, yCordinate);` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately the code in the question is rather incomplete and does not show in particular the initialization of the text matrix in each text object and also has many undefined variables.

Thus, here a piece of code as an example that results in a text - line - text output:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
float fontSize = 14;
float fontHeight = fontSize;
float leading = 20;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Date date = new Date();

PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);

float yCordinate = page.getCropBox().getUpperRightY() - 30;
float startX = page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX() + 30;
float endX = page.getCropBox().getUpperRightX() - 30;

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, yCordinate);
contentStream.showText("Entry Form – Header");
yCordinate -= fontHeight;  //This line is to track the yCordinate
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
yCordinate -= leading;
contentStream.showText("Date Generated: " + dateFormat.format(date));
yCordinate -= fontHeight;
contentStream.endText(); // End of text mode

contentStream.moveTo(startX, yCordinate);
contentStream.lineTo(endX, yCordinate);
contentStream.stroke();
yCordinate -= leading;

contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, yCordinate);
contentStream.showText("Name: XXXXX");
contentStream.endText();

contentStream.close();
doc.save("textLineText.pdf");
```

*([TextAndGraphics.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/TextAndGraphics.java#L38) test `testDrawTextLineText`)*

This code results in:

[image: Screenshot]

If you want different distances, you'll have to adapt the `yCordinate -= ...` lines before and after the drawing of the graphical line.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for the solution. It worked for me. The code block that you have added in the answer part is similar to my code. 

I have missed to put `yCordinate -= leading;` after the line is drawn (`contentStream.stroke();`). After I have added it, it worked fine for me,